# Converting single value lists into strings within a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframes that each contains a column of lists.

In one dataframe though, the lists are all a single item and there are many duplicates in different rows. I want to combine the duplicates with groupby/agg, but that method can't take the data in list form.

I am trying to convert the data to a non-list format with `df['index'] = df['index'].apply(lambda lst: [lst[0]])`, to  get the 0th element, but I get the output below which is completely unchanged, still in list format.

```
            index   count
0            [_w]  254110
1      [Arg34His]    4614
2      [Asp32Asn]    4455
3      [Trp30Ter]    4248
4      [Trp30Ter]    4159
...           ...     ...
71117  [Trp30Arg]       1
71118  [Thr27Ala]       1
71119  [Asp32Gly]       1
71120  [Lys12Ile]       1
71121  [Asn22Lys]       1
```

Comment: You remove and also add `[]`, need `df['index'] = df['index'].str[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I just learned how to use lambda functions yesterday and I thought those brackets were required. I had no idea I have been adding them to everything I return.

Comment: ya, if remove them by `lst[0]` instead `[lst[0]]` your solution working also.